# Ingress controller does not show external IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I have been trying to create a kubernetes cluster on Google kubernetes Engine. My pods are sucessfully running but the problem is with the ingress controller. The ingress conroller is not showing the external IP to access the application.

[image]

And the YAML file for nginx ingress controller looks like this :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-ingress
  labels:
    app: ingress  
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing 
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"    
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: nodeapp1svc
          servicePort: 80      
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: nodeapp2svc
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /app2
        backend:
          serviceName: nodeapp2svc
          servicePort: 80
```

What can I do next?

Comment: I don't know the impact of your current annotations. Did you tried without?

Comment: Just noticed `nginx-ingress` tag under your question. Is it placed by mistake or you use indeed this specific **ingress controller** ? You didn't mention it in your question however. Have you deployed it on your **GKE cluster** ? Keep in mind that it differs from the default **ingress-gce** and if you want to use it you need to set it up first.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is related with your `annotations`, specifically with this one:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
```

The `ingress.class` you're trying to use is something specific to **Azure AKS** so definitely you cannot use it on your **GKE Cluster**.

Note that you can omit `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` annotation at all if you want your default **GKE Ingress controller** - [ingress-gce](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce) to be used.

I tested it on my GKE cluster and without the mentioned above annotation it works just fine.

As to your specific setup, I noticed one more problem, namely your `nodeapp[1-3]svc` `Services` are of a type `ClusterIP` and they need to be either `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`.

If you run:

```
kubectl describe ingress http-ingress
```

and take a look at the `events` section, you may encounter the error message like the one below:

```
loadbalancer-controller  error while evaluating the ingress spec: service "default/nodeapp1svc" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"
```

**Summary:**

1. use the correct `ingress.class` i.e. omit this annotation at all and the default ingress controller will be used.
2. make sure your backends are exposed via `NodePort` rather than `ClusterIP`.

Comment: It's still not working. I tried doing both the things you told.

Comment: Has your **ingress resource** received the external IP address ? If not, can you see anything in `events` ?